# Legend name in ggplot - renaming

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem with changing the legend name for the below plot

```
qplot(date, pce, data=economics, colour=psavert,
      main="Konsumpcja i oszczędności w czasie", xlab="Data", ylab="Konsumpcja w mln USD")
```

I would like to change the name "psavert" for "Savings", but remain the dependance between pce and psavert data.

Do you have any ideas? :)

Comment: try adding `labs(colour = "savings")`.

Comment: I have an error: `mapping` must be created by `aes()`

Comment: I would use `ggplot` rather than `qplot` - there is a lot more info about how to use it. `ggplot(economics, aes(x=date, y = pce, colour = psavert)) + geom_point() + labs(x = "Data", y = "k...", colour  = "savings", title = "k...")`